# Magento2.3 installation issue on wamp Winodws 10

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, wamp

I am asking this question after several attempt to install magento2.3 on windows10 WAMP. Every time the installation stops and shows error at zero percent or at 70 percent or in between. Lot of people advised to try it on Ubuntu but that is not possible because our company using Windows10 as OS and not permitted to use Ubuntu.

**The steps/configuration that i follows for Magento 2.3 installation on WAMP**

1. Wamp Version 3.1.7
2. PHP 7.1.26
3. Apache 2.4.23
4. Enabled Open SSL
5. Set max_execution_time = 18000
6. Set memory_limit = 2G
7. max_input_time = 1800
8. Enabled Exception  printing
9. Set Full permission to magento folder/files (777)
10. Then setup virtual host in The Directory "D"

**Virtual Host Settings**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@local.mage230ce.com
DocumentRoot "D:/Projects/mage230ce"
ServerName local.mage230ce.com
ErrorLog "logs/local.mage230ce.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/local.mage230ce.com-error-access.log" common

<Directory "D:/Projects/mage230ce">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

</Directory>
```

Then runs the url now stops at 0 percent **Installing... 0%** Please check the below image

[image]

**System.log**

```
main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
```

**debug.log**

```
 main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] []
```

**install.log**

> Starting Magento installation:
>   File permissions check...
>   [Progress: 1 / 773]
>   Required extensions check...
>   [Progress: 2 / 773]
>   Enabling Maintenance Mode...
>   [Progress: 3 / 773]
>   Installing deployment configuration...
>   [Progress: 4 / 773]
>   Installing database schema:
>   Schema creation/updates:

Please check the above issue and guide me..

Comment: Please check max execution limit, max post in php.ini.

Comment: @user55548  The values 
max_execution_time = 18000
post_max_size = 8M

Comment: Change it to max_execution_time = 36000, memory_limit = 36000M, max_input_time 3600

Comment: @user55548 Still same problem

Comment: @JordySChemparathy Did you install in windows?

Answer (score 0):

And all my efforts towards installing magento2.3 from browser becomes failed and installed magento2.3 using composer. Please check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/composer.html
for more details

Please note that, Since our OS  is windows, Windows uses "\" as separator so we need to edit core file:

```
magento_root\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

> Search for **$realPath** and replace it with **$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solution but one working for me

You need to do following things.
1. Open this file.

```
vendor\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
```

2. Fine this function

   protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)

Spoiler
arround line no. 133

3. Now replace

`$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);` arround line no. 138

to

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

4. Run following commands from CLI.

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

It works for me.

Grab it from: 
https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Magento-2-3-0-after-installation-problem-with-WAMP/td-p/122785

Answer (score 0):

Magento is not compatible with windows. See here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements.html#operating-systems-linux-x86-64

Please use Linux in Docker, with Hyper-V or Vagrant to run Magento on a Windows PC.